# Implement logger scope without sending dependency

Tags: c#, variables, scope

I need to create a logger that should have a scope (something similar to the `TransactionScope` class).

Here is a sketch:

```
public class Logger
{
    private static Logger instance;

    public void BeginScope(string scopeName)
    {
        //...
    }

    public static Logger Instance()
    {
        // Singleton code
        return instance;
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.Writeline(string.Concat(scopeName, message));
    }

    public void EndScope()
    {
        //...
    }   
}
```

How to create the logger scope so that after I begin the scope, if I create many classes and use there the singleton logger, it will use the same scope, but without sending a dependency? I cannot use the scope as dependency when I'm logging inside classes.

And also if I have the code:

```
for(var i = 0;i>2000;i++)
{
    Logger.BeginScope("scope_" + i);
    //create classes that contain methods that logs data
    Logger.EndScope();  
}
```

It should create a scope at each loop.

Comment: Do you know about [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)? They already implemented probably all you will ever need from logging, even those functionalities that you may not be currently aware of.

Comment: I need to create the proof of concept regarding the scope and logger is just an example...

Comment: Having said that, I don't understand your question. Trying to figure out if NLog can do what you want, but not sure what that is.

Comment: I don't need a logger, I need to create a proof of concept that use the scope as I presented above. And to create a practical example, I've chosen the logger.

Comment: Why not just add `private static string scopeName`? It wont work recursively, or in multi-threaded code, but otherwise it's simple.

Comment: But I need to work in a multi-thread environment and with the static variable I cannot have two open scopes at the same time

Comment: So you want one instance of `Logger` that can handle several instances of scope at the same time?

Comment: Yes. And also when I'm logging, I don't want to send the scope reference

Comment: Why not just have several instances of `Logger` and scope member that is not static? Or if creating `Logger` is expensive have one instance of `Logger` but also one more class `Scope`, whose functions you call, which are then passed to `Logger`, with member `scopeName` passed along. Or (same thing with different naming) move expensive stuff from `Logger` to another class, that `Logger` references as member, and have scope name also as member of `Logger`.

Comment: Do you need recursive scopes?

Comment: If I create a scope inside another scope, the second scope should be a separate scope and when I close it, the logger should use the first scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sketch:

```
public class Logger {
    // use thread local variable - will have separate instance per thread
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<Logger> _instance = new ThreadLocal<Logger>(() => new Logger());
    // scopes stack
    private readonly Stack<string> _scopes = new Stack<string>();

    public static void BeginScope(string scopeName) {
        // push new scope to the stack
        _instance.Value._scopes.Push(scopeName);
    }

    public static void Log(string message) {
        // use scope from the top of the stack (first check if not null)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(_instance.Value._scopes.Peek(), message));
    }

    public static void EndScope() {
        // remove scope from the top
        _instance.Value._scopes.Pop();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Logger.BeginScope("scope_" + i);               
    Logger.Log("test");
    Logger.BeginScope("inner scope_" + i);
    Logger.Log("test");                
    Logger.EndScope();
    Logger.Log("test"); // back to scope_i
    Logger.EndScope();
}
```

Comment: This would not work if I begin a scope, from another class/method I begin another scope and then I close the first scope. But it's a nice idea...

Comment: How is that? If you begin first scope, then second - you can only close second, not first. Otherwise it's not "scope".

Comment: Imagine this implementation in a web api and I have two controllers. I can close the scopes based on how much time the execution takes on each controller

Comment: Still don't get it, maybe you can clarify more with an example. What should happen if you started scope A, then scope B, then closed scope A without closing B (all that in the same thread)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with threads. Compare the logger scope with the variable scope but the scope will be visible and in the new created objects. Image a wpf application with two buttons: on each button click event you begin a logger scope and end it when the code completes. You don't know what click event will be done first

Comment: Still don't see a problem. First button click starts scope "button1". Then every class that uses Logger.Log will use scope "button1". Then scope ends. Second handler starts scope "button2" and the same applies.

Comment: No, the button1 scope will be used in every class that is created in button1_click_event or have methods execute in this method. For the button2 scope, the same. I can have two scopes simultanous

Comment: In my answer, any class that will use Logger.Log after scope "button1" is created, will use that scope, regardless of where and how that class was created. You started "button1" scope - all logs after that point will have "button1" prefix. But that discussion looks pointless until you provide some (pseudo-code) example of what exactly you want it seems.

Comment: Maybe you missed that in my example all methods (BeginScope, EndScope, Log) are static, not instance...

Answer (score 0):

Given that all your logging happens through `Logger.Instance()` (i.e. no one ever saves the instance for later use), just replace the instance in `BeginScope`:

```
public void BeginScope(string scopeName)
{
    _savedInstance = _instance;
    _instance = new LoggerForScope( scopeName );
}

public void EndScope()
{
    _instance = _savedInstance;
}
```

But this is horribly ugly, and will fail if scopes overlap.

EDIT:

What about this? Use the scope to log. But then, you have to pass the logger to the method that wants to log...

```
for(var i = 0;i<2000;i++)
{
    using (var scopedLogger = Logger.BeginScope("scope_" + i))
    {
        // use the scoped logger here
    }
 }
```

You cannot have both, I guess, the ubiquitous static instance and an individual scope.

Comment: this won't work if I have to log from different places in the same time

Comment: Sure, but then the static singleton won't work in the first place, and your problem's not only the scope.